How to Solve a Least Absolute Deviation Problem in R
We have the following time series model:
$$y_t=a+b\cdot t+e_t\quad\text{for}\quad t=1,\ldots,T$$
where $y_t$ is the observation at instant $t$, $e_t$ is an AR(1), i.e.
$$e_t=\psi\cdot e_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t\quad\text{with}\quad  t=2,\ldots,T$$
where $\varepsilon_t$ is a Laplace white noise. To estimate the parameters of this model ($a$, $b$, $\psi$, and $\sigma$, $\sigma$ being the variance of the noise) using maximum likelihood, we use the following objective function:
$$\frac{\sum_{t=2}^{T}\left|\left(y_t-a-b\cdot t\right)-\psi\left(y_{t-1}-a-b\cdot(t-1)\right)\right|}{T}$$
Question: How to find the estimates $a$, $b$, and $\psi$ by minimizing this $l1$-norm using a solver in R? I tried the lp function from the lpSolve package, and the ROI package, but the results were not good.
Here is how the data is generated in R:
# Define parameters
T <- 100
a0 <- 1
b0 <- 2
psi0 <- 0.5
sigma0 <- 1

# Function to generate Laplace-distributed noise
rlaplace <- function(n, scale) {
  return(rexp(n, rate = 1/scale) - rexp(n, rate = 1/scale))
}

# Simulate data with Laplace noise
simulate_data_laplace <- function(T, a0, b0, psi0, sigma0) {
  e <- rlaplace(T, scale = sigma0)  # Generate Laplace noise
  y <- numeric(T)
  y[1] <- e[1]
  for (t in 2:T) {
    y[t] <- a0 + b0 * t + psi0 * y[t-1] + e[t]
  }
  return(y)
}

y_laplace <- simulate_data_laplace(T, a0, b0, psi0, sigma0)

Any help or hint would be much appreciated.

After waiting several hours, I did the following:
I wrote an algorithm that generates data according to the description and code above.
I then used four methods; one iterative method, and solver-based methods: optim, nloptr, and DEoptim.
For the initial values, I used the lm function results to obtain better results.
The results of the 100 replications are shown below:

The four algorithms tend to underestimate $\psi$, the reason is not clear.
